# Laravel loging can't find a route

Tags: php, laravel, logging, routes

I am creating Laravel 5 application.
I stuck with loggig problem.

Here are my routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// route to show the login form
Route::get('/login', array('uses' => 'HandleController@login'));
// route to process the form
Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'HandleController@handleLogin'));
```

My HandleContrroler and it's methodes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

class HandleController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
      return view('login');
    }

    public function handleLogin(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);
      $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
      if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
          return redirect()->intended('home');
      }

      return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email' => 'Username or password is invalid']);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
      \Auth::logout();
      return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

I don't there should be a problem with my view file.
When I am going to the projcet/directory/login in my web browser I am getting **NotFoundHttpException**. Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Laravel provides authentication out of the box just create database, run this command the following command and authenticate is ready.                       php artisan make:auth

Comment: try this Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HandleController@login'));

Comment: That single line dind't helped. I would prefer workaround on my version to better know the mechanichs

Answer (score 0):

After logout you are redirecting to route with name login, which doesn't exist.

**SOLUTION:**
In the routes.php add a name to your login route.

```
// route to show the login form
Route::get('/login', array('uses' => 'HandleController@login'))->name('login');
```